# I cannot understand mistake lmer

Tags: random, lme4, mixed-models

I tried to solve the problem reading other answers but did not get the solution.
I am performing a lmer model:

`MODHET <- lmer(PERC ~ SITE + TREAT + HET + TREAT*HET + (1|PINE), data = PRESU)`.

Perc is the percentage of predation. Site is a categorical variable that I am using as blocking factor. It is site identity where I performed the experiement. TREAT is categorical variable of 2 levels. HET is a continuous variable. The number of observation is 56 divided in 7 sites
Maybe the problem is how I expressed the random factor. In every site I selected 8 pines among 15 to perform the experiment. I included the  pine identity as categorical random factor. For instance in Site 1 pines are called a1,a3,a7 ecc, while in site 2 are called b1,b4,b12 ecc... 
The output of the model is

`Error: number of levels of each grouping factor must be < number of observations`

I don´t understand where is the mistake. Could it be how I called the pines? 
I tried also

`MODHET <- lmer(PERC ~ SITE + TREAT + HET + TREAT*HET + (1|SITE:PINE), data = PRESU)`

but the output is the same.
I hope that I explained well my problems. I read on this forum similar questions about it but I still do not get the solution.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use argument `control = lmerControl(check.nobs.vs.nRE = "ignore")` in your lmer-call to suppress this error. However, I guess this does not solve the actual problem. It seems to me that your grouping level contains no "groups", probably "SITE" is your random intercept?

If you consider PINES nested as "subjects" within SITES, then I would suggest following formula:

```
MODHET <- lmer(PERC ~ TREAT*HET + (1|SITE), data = PRESU)
```

or,

```
MODHET <- lmer(PERC ~ TREAT*HET + (1 | SITE / PINE), data = PRESU)
```

But my answer may be wrong, I'm not sure whether I have enough information to fully understand what you're aiming at.

**edit:**
Sorry, nesting was not correctly specified, I fixed it in the above formula. See also [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/79392) .

Comment: Hej Daniel, thank you for your reply. I will try to explain better the aim of the experiement. I want to test predation rate in 7 different sites (Site 1,2,3,ecc...) In each site I selected randomly 8 pines. These  pines have been choosen  among 15 used for a previous experiement. So they are called (a1,a3,a7 for Site 1, b2,b6,b7 for SIte2 ecc..). SIte and Pines ar defined as categorical. In each site, the pines were divided by two treatments (Wood presence or not). These more information maybe can help. Since pines are "inside" each sites I guess the second one could work. I will try it.

Comment: Sorry, I had a mistake in my formular and fixed it. Furthermore, when specifying `TREAT*HET`, this expands to `TRET + HET + TREAT : HET`, so you don't need to include `TRET + HET`.

Comment: Hej Daniel, thank you for the help. I solved the problem!